# How can I split this vector?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSql, I have a table like this:

```
mytable
id | samples
1  | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

I want to split this samples dividing into **samples of three positions**, to have a result like this:

```
id | samples
1  | 1, 2, 3
1  | 4, 5, 6
1  | 7, 8
```

I've tried to use unnest, but the result is:

```
id | samples
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
1  | 4
...
```

Do you guys know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema design - storing comma separated lists of integers - makes this hard. This isn't a "vector", it's a string. [Don't store lists of values as comma separated strings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788).

You can work around this by parsing the string dynamically, though performance will suck.

With sample setup:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(id integer primary key, samples text);
INSERT INTO mytable(id, samples) VALUES (1, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8');
```

You can get the array form:

```
SELECT id, string_to_array(samples, ', ')::integer[] FROM mytable;
```

then split the array up into slices and turn it back into a string by joining against `generate_series` with a start of 1 (i.e. the first array index position), a step of 3, and an end value of the array length.

```
WITH mytable_fixed(id, samples) AS (
    SELECT id, string_to_array(samples, ', ')::integer[] FROM mytable
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    array_to_string(samples[step:step+2], ', ') 
FROM mytable_fixed, 
     LATERAL generate_series(1, array_length(samples, 1), 3) step;
```